# Is assigning to a field of temporary object undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address, temporary

I compiled the following code with gcc and clang with `-O1` and `-std=c++20` flags, and it seems to work as expected.

```
#include <iostream>

struct S { int i; };

template<typename T>
T *get_address(T&& t) { return &t; }

void print_value_from_temporary(S *const s) {
    std::cout << s->i << '\n';
    s->i = 0;
    std::cout << s->i << '\n';
}

int main() {
    print_value_from_temporary(get_address(S{42}));
}
```

My question is: Is the `s->i = 0;` line an undefined behavior?

Comment: this is fine since access to instance of this class do not exceeds lifetime of object (temporary). Temporary object will be alive until all functions in this line are completed, so including `print_value_from_temporary`.

Comment: Validity of such access is not related to if object is temporary or not, but if it is destroyed yet or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is the `s->i = 0;` line an undefined behavior?

No. The [temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) will be destroyed after the full expression, which includes the execution of the function body of `print_value_from_temporary`. For `s->i = 0;` in `print_value_from_temporary` the temporary has not been destroyed yet.

> All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created,